# Инициализатор типа "System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1" выдал исключение

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Пытаюсь сделать миграцию на MySqlServer, но при `Add-Migration` выдает эту ошибку.

Установлены:
Mysql Connector NET 8.0.15, MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8, MySQL.Data 8.0.15, MySQL.Data.Entity 6.10.8, EF6 6.2.0

Файл конфигурации

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
 <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
 </configSections>

<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
 <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
 </providers>
</entityFramework>
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="inspectm_inspectContext" connectionString="server=--;user id=--;password=--;database=--;persistsecurityinfo=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: `выдает эту ошибку` какую?

Comment: @tym32167 которая в заголовке

Comment: `Инициализатор типа “System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration1” выдал исключение` какое именно исключение выдал Инициализатор типа?

Comment: @tym32167 мне просто в nuget консоли вылазит эта ошибка, больше ничего

Comment: Тогда проблема. По тому, что вы привели, сказать ничего не возможно

Comment: @tym32167 И что делать тогда? `Try-Catch` же туда не вставишь

Comment: ну попробуйте создать этот тип вручную, или попробуйте создать миграцию а чистом проекте

Comment: @tym32167 а вручную как создать?

Comment: Попробуйте add-migration -verbose если даст больше информации об ошибке, дополните вопрос.